# want read a specific item from data() method in firestore

Tags: json, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

```
snapshot.forEach(doc => {
  console.log("ID: "+doc.id, '=>', "Doc DATA: "+JSON.stringify(doc.data()));
});
```

I want to read only 1 item from doc.data() and that is an array of strings called ("supportedCurrencies").
How do i read? I'm new to firestore and TS so any help much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: If `supportedCurrencies` is a key in data, you can try `doc.data().supportedCurrencies.join(", ")`

Comment: what does .join(", ") means here?

Comment: it creates a string from the array and joins adds the given string in the middle of the elements. so `[a, b, c].join('|')` would give you `"a|b|c"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `doc.data()` you get a plain JavaScript object whose properties are each of the fields in the document:

```
const data = doc.data();
```

If you want one of those fields, just access it by name as a property of that object:

```
const supportedCurrencies = data.supportedCurrencies;
```

If it's an array, then you can treat it just like any other JavaScript [array object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).